# How using georeferenced image in a plot of points in R?

Tags: r, plot, raster

I'm plotting the plot below using R's plot function. This plot 
represented in the form of different point values, was obtained from different locations along the coast of Brazil in South America. The Colour points in a plot differ depending on a vector of values.

[image]

To better represent the South America coast in this plot, I would like to insert a georeferenced file of image below showing the shoreline. I want that the points stay on the shoreline for better representation. It's possible to do this in R?

[image]

I already have a georeferenced image and I'm using the code below to making the plot of points.

```
coordinates = data[,2:3]
groups = data[,4:9]

## Scale the groups so they are all between 0 and 1
max.groups = max(groups)
min.groups = min(groups)
scaled.groups = (groups-min.groups)/(max.groups-min.groups)
# Plot with color gradient
max.saz = max(groups$G1)
min.saz = min(groups$G1)
scaled.saz = (groups$G1-min.saz)/(max.saz-min.saz)
## Colors ranging from red (very) to blue (little)
saz.colors = rgb(red=scaled.saz,green=0,blue=(1-scaled.saz))
plotG1 = plot(coordinates$long, coordinates$lat, pch = 16, cex = 2, col = saz.colors, bg = saz.colors, xlab="Longitude (Wº)", ylab="Latitude (Sº)")
```

Comment: what kind of georeferenced file do you have? a shapefile?

Comment: no, it's just an image georeferenced in TIF format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a general example:

```
library(raster)
bra <- getData('GADM', country='BRA', level=0)
crd <- matrix(c(-44.53, -38.61, -35.91, -37.96, -42, -35.1, -40.5, -45.83, -37.11, -43.85, -1.9, -12.74, -9.88, -12.5, -2.79, -8.69, -20.67, -1.19, -4.94, -2.48), ncol=2)

plot(bra)
points(crd, pch=20, col=topo.colors(10), cex=2)
```

To get just the coastline:

```
x <- as(bra, 'SpatialLines')
plot(x)
y <- crop(x, drawExtent())
# draw a box on the plot by clicking in two corners
# wait for 10 secs.
```

Now

```
plot(y)
points(crd, pch=20, col=topo.colors(10), cex=2)
```

But you say you have a georeferenced image. In principle (assuming that it has the same coordinate reference system) you should be able to do something like this:

```
r <- raster("image.tif")
plot(r)
points(crd, pch=20, col=topo.colors(10), cex=2)
```

Comment: Thank you Robert for your help. I successfully make a plot of my points in Brazil map. But i intend to use only the shoreline of Brazil or South America in my plot. Because of this i got an georeferenced image like the picture above. Do you know how can i use this georeferenced image or another way to get only the shoreline in R ?

Comment: I have added an example of how you can go about that to my answer.

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for your code about to get just the coastline. It's a useful and simple way to make it. Before seeing your answer, i tried to use the georeferenced image as your suggestion above (r <- raster("image.tif")). I succeed but i didn't like the result, because the image appears with green background and I want to work with the original colors of the image. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it with ggplot2 (riffing off of @RobertH):

```
library(raster)
library(rgeos)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
library(viridis)

# retrieve map
bra <- getData('GADM', country='BRA', level=0)

# simplify the map so it plots more quickly
bra_simpl <- gSimplify(bra, 0.01, topologyPreserve=TRUE)

# make it work with ggplot2
bra_map <- fortify(bra_simpl)

# simulate some data
dots <- data.frame(x=c(-44.53, -38.61, -35.91, -37.96, -42, -35.1,
                       -40.5, -45.83, -37.11, -43.85),
                   y=c(-1.9, -12.74, -9.88, -12.5, -2.79, -8.69, -20.67, 
                       -1.19, -4.94, -2.48),
                   value=sample(100, 10))

gg <- ggplot()
# lay down base layer
gg <- gg + geom_map(map=bra_map, data=bra_map,
                    aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=id),
                    color="#2b2b2b", size=0.15, fill=NA)
# plot your points
gg <- gg + geom_point(data=dots, aes(x=x, y=y, color=value), size=4)
# better colors
gg <- gg + scale_color_viridis()
# projection & limit map viewport
gg <- gg + coord_map(xlim=c(-53,-34), ylim=c(-30,0))
# clean map plot
gg <- gg + theme_map()
# legend on right
gg <- gg + theme(legend.position="right")
gg
```

[image]

`geom_raster` can work with fortified, georeferenced images.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your detailed example with ggplot2 . I'm very interested in working with this function, because  of their good results and good legend. But when i run this particular code gg<- ggplot(), in your example above, I received the following error message: Error in list2env(members, envir = e) : names(x) must be a character vector of the same length as x.